# Reading line from terminal in expl3

Tags: expl3, terminal-output

Simple question: How do you read a line from terminal to a token list variable in `expl3`?

The following is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\read \c_term_ior to \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

\ior_get:NN \c_term_ior \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

resulting in the expected behavior for the `\read` version, but in `\q_no_value` for the `\ior_get:NN` version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `\ior_get_term:nN` (or perhaps `\ior_str_get_term:nN`), added as candidates in March 2019. You'd do something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_get_term:nN { Foo ~ bar } \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Due to an internal change of how input streams are managed, to make the check whether they are open more robust, the effect is that `\ior_get:NN` no longer works with `\c_term_ior` and for this reason `\ior_get_term:Nn` has been introduced. Unfortunately, the documentation wasn't updated to reflect this.